# Can I install mate 16.04 lts on ubuntu 14.04 lts?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, lts, mate, metacity

I use ubuntu 14.04 lts. Can I isntall ubuntu mate 16.04 lts without first installing ubuntu 16.04 lts? 
Also, i use gnome classic (metacity). After istalling mate, should I be able to use this again?

Comment: Thank all very much for your answers! I think i will just install mate 14.04 and then try to upgrade to 16.04. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When you install MATE desktop on top of vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 you get the version available at the 14.04 repositories. Only if done from an already installed 16.04 you would get the same MATE desktop for 16.04.

You can install UbuntuMATE directly if that's what you want to have in the end.

https://ubuntu-mate.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you want 16.04, you need to install 16.04.

Ubuntu MATE is just normal Ubuntu, just without Unity and with GNOME 2 instead. If you want the MATE desktop environment, you'll have to do one of two things.

You can install the MATE DE through the terminal and then upgrade, before removing Unity. It's a bit of a hacky method, but it almost always works. Of course, you can always just keep both desktop environments.

You can also try (doesn't always work) downloading MATE 16.04 and burning it to a DVD or USB. Usually, trying to install a newer version of Ubuntu over an older one will allow you to upgrade the current installation, but the option doesn't always exist. If you don't see it, you'll have to install MATE and remove Unity.

I'm not sure what you'd want to keep using GNOME Classic after installing MATE, since MATE is pretty much GNOME Classic (2.x).

The easiest method is probably to install the MATE desktop environment and then upgrade to 16.04, removing Unity afterward if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually mean install or did you mean upgrade?

- Install? Yes.
- Upgrade? No.

If you want to install 16.04 Mate ... create a backup of your personal files, download and burn the ISO as you did with your current install, boot from it and install your Mate over your current operating system with any of the options offered.

Upgrade? Nope. The 2 systems use different default software so an upgrade is not possible. If you want an upgrade you either replace the desktop with Mate in your current 14.04 and then upgrade to 16.04 or upgrade your current 14.04 to 16.04 and then replace the desktop with Mate.

> Also, i use gnome classic (metacity). After istalling mate, should I be able to use this again?

Sure, you can install multiple desktops. And they are interchangeable. Again: you probably are asking the wrong question. If you install Mate you remove any other desktop. You can add other desktops to your system or replace desktops but within that version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(mate-desktop))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(mate-desktop))))'
apt-get install mate-desktop
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/systemd
apt-get update
apt-get install systemd libpam-systemd systemd-ui
apt-get dist-upgrade
cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
nano /etc/default/grub
```

In the open file leave this line so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "init=/lib/systemd/systemd"
```

Continue running:

```
update-grub
ln -fs /proc/self/mounts /etc/mtab
```

Reboot your system,

With any problems, to undo changes run:

```
exec sudo -i
mv /etc/default/grub.bak /etc/default/grub
update-grub
```

If everything goes fine, and to upgrade to new available version:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
update-manager -d
```

Software Updater will show up and search for the new release, after a few seconds, you will see a screen like below that saying:

However, Ubuntu 16.04 is available now.

Press the button Upgrade to start upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.

The Software Updater will ask you to confirm still you want to upgrade, press Start Upgrade to begin installing Ubuntu 16.04.

Now, the Software Updater will prepare to start setting up new software channels, and after a few minutes, the software updater will notify you the details the number of packages are going to be removed, and number of packages are going to be installed, press Start upgrade to continue.

Ended the dist-upgrade, reboot your system and:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall mate-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```